# Global variable with vue instance not defined

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, webpack, vue.js

I'm defining the Vue.js instance like this in `app.js`:

```
const vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        page: 'welcome'
    }
});
```

and using Laravel's default webpack script:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Vue is loading correctly as the components are displaying and the Vue developer plugin is showing appropriate data.

However, in the developer console and in scripts on the page `vm` is not defined.
For instance on the page that is loading a Vue component

```
<script>
  console.log(vm); // Error: vm is not defined.
</script>
```

How do I access the Vue instance? I want to set a one of its data properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have flexibility and import with any name, you can use default exports.

In **app.js**:

```js
export default new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        page: 'welcome'
    }
});
```

In **other .js** files:

```js
import whateverName from './app';
```

Naturally, adjusting the `./app` depending on where the file is at.

Comment: I like your generalized answer better than mine.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to use

```
export {
  vm
};

require('./main');
```

and in `main.js`

```
import {vm} from './app';
```